# XCode round rect buttons acting wonky

Tags: button, rounding, rect

Does anyone else deal with buttons acting funny like this? (link below)  I have no idea what causes it, or how to fix it. In the past I have re-saved all my PNG files, reimported them and it worked.  But this time, all the PNG files are working fine on a different view controller, so I'm lost and hoping someone might offer some insight.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/g4iWI.png

Answer (score 0):

Try selecting your button then go to the attributes inspector and if `Autoresize Subviews` is checked, uncheck it.

That worked for me.